# Shopping Cart Not Working On All Pages

Tags: checkout, cart

Please help.

My online store's shopping cart is not working on all pages.
I cannot go to the checkout page after I added an item to the cart, the store's cart is always empty.

[image]

When I check the console that's the error that shows up. I think that this error is what's causing the cart to not function.

[image]

**Please help**

Comment: Try to disable all third party extension one by one and then check. so you get idea from where that conflict comes.

Comment: I am new to Magento. The only way  I know how to disable modules is to go to Admin >> Stores >> Settings >> configuration >> system >> advanced. Is that how I can disable them?

Comment: Go to app/etc/config.php and disable a module by changing it's value from 1 to 0.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying it now

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file system permissions and perform the proper deployment steps

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

```
Deployment steps:
```

Update the database schema and data:
bin/magento setup:upgrade

Exit maintenance mode:
bin/magento maintenance:enable

Compile the code:
bin/magento setup:di:compile

Deploy static content:
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Clean the cache:
bin/magento cache:clean

Exit maintenance mode:
bin/magento maintenance:disable

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it but unfortunately, it did not work